# In what forms does Android return EXIF GPS data?

Tags: java, android, gps, exif

I am using the EXIF data from the photos taken with Android phones and generally it is quite simple to get the GPS data and it is returned in a simple [double latitude, double longtitude] format and it works great.  But sometimes it will give me numbers that don't make sense such as [247322, 124390] and I am guessing that this is because it is returning them to me in a different format but I'm not sure what.

Do you know what the different formats EXIF GPS data is returned in?

Here is my code:

```
            var gps = GetImageGps(filePath, currentTimeInMillisenconds);
            double latitude = 0;
            double longitude = 0;

            if (gps != null && gps[0] != 0 && gps[1] != 0)
            {
                _gpsLocation = gps;
                latitude = gps[0];
                longitude = gps[1];

                if ((latitude < -90 || latitude > 90) && (longitude < -180 || latitude > 180))
                {
                    //here I will handle another format
                }
            }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#getLatLong%28float%5b%5d%29) in GetImageGps?

Try it something like this (make sure to use the getLatLong method)

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(fileName);
float[] latLng = new float[2];
if (exifInterface .getLatLong(latLng)) { //file has exif latlong info
   //etc, latLng[0] is your latitute value and latLng[1] your longitude value
}
```

Comment: yes it is basically the same thing but for Monodroid (Android with C#) but does that always just return [degrees]? Or will it sometimes return the [degrees, minutes, seconds]?

Comment: check http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/images/access_image_metadata and http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AAndroid.Media.ExifInterface.GetLatLong(System.Single%5B%5D)